# Display output from Python script on third-part website

Tags: python, file-upload

I have a Python script that runs continuously, outputting results as it goes. I'd like to monitor these remotely, and ideally display them on a website. This could be as straightforward as periodically uploading a properly-formatted file (results.html) to be displayed on a site hosted on a cheap webhost. However, I haven't been able to find a clear way of doing this (uploading - creating the html file is fine). I am keen to keep things as simple as possible as I'm a relative beginner with Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to output it to a simple html file and use triple quotes to make a multiline print:

```
file=open("results.html", "w")
file.write("""
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>results</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">


</head>

<body>
 <p>"""your_content"""</p>
</body>
</html>
""")
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question was around how to upload the file - creating it is fairly easy.

Comment: You could go for a hosting service that hosts the file in a specific folder on your computer. That way if you make the python script output the results to results.html and then add a delay and a loop it would continuously update the file, and the hosting service would see that the file is updated, and sync that file to their server. However the easiest way to do this, for free, would be to host it on something like Dropbox or Google Drive, but that wouldn't be sufficient if you are going to use php.

Comment: Thanks Toasterino, that's not a bad suggestion for a quick-and-dirty solution. I could upload the html page using Dropbox's API. Ideally I'd find a (slightly) more sophisticated solution later, but this is a helpful start.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)